# Using the gerund as an English analogue of Russian verbal participles

Tags: translation, gerunds, participles, russian

Could you please verify that using the gerund is normal as an analogue of Russian verbal participles in the following phrase:

The device automatically estimates calories, consumed from food, **basing** on data from bioimpedance sensor.

**UPD:**So, the main thing is that
"...*estimates* ... *based*..." seems like there have to be NOUN instead of "estimates"
and "...estimates...basing..." looks very similar to gerund, like in
"I like skating"/"I estimate basing"

Comment: I don't know Russian but 'basing' sounds wrong, and 'based' would sound natural. But also '_The_ device' is how you say it.

Comment: Thank you, @Mitch, i've ellipsed the article, but still confused about the form for base

as for me ,confused from food, seems nonessentional addition, interrupting the main flow as in the next phrase:
"The hotel, once we finally found it, was very nice."
so, the base of the sentence would be:
"The device automatically estimates calories basing/based on (a?) data from bioimpedance sensor.

*articles, hate em =)

could you please say, which of the variants basing/based seems more natural to you?

Comment: So isn't "NOUN3 + estimates -> based" wrong?
Always thought that it could be only smth like "...performs estimation based" not "estimates based"

Comment: As I mentioned already, 'basing' is unnatural and 'based' is very natural, but I have no idea about the original (which you should give for any kind of translation question).

Comment: No, a past participle is required: "Device automatically estimates calories consumed from food, **based** on data from bioimpedance sensor".

Comment: Re: 'estimates', you can say it naturally two ways, 'The device estimates calories based on...' ('estimate' used as a verb) or 'The device performs estimation of calories based on...'; both are perfectly natural. (the 'based on part is irrelevant)

Comment: You could have say 'relying on.' But it's not a gerund either;  it's another compound preposition, like 'based on,' or 'in *lieu* of' (Latin *pro)*  or 'in the presence of.' Instead of a compound preposition you could use a simple preposition"food, from data from... sensor." (from/from would be clumsy but correct)

Comment: Thank you all! Seems clear to me now!

Comment: Now about "The" article at the beginning - could one omit it if it's an advertising text made for mostly american English speaking auditory?
"The device performs the automatic estimation of calories, consumed from food, based on a data from bioimpedance sensor."
OR
"Device performs the automatic estimation of calories, consumed from food, based on a data from bioimpedance sensor.

Comment: *Basing* ***on data*** is wrong. But you could say *basing (its)*  ***data on***. Also note that it should either be ***a*** *bioimpendance sensor* or *bioimpendance* ***sensors***.